# Pass Value from Request Header in custom Attribute / Annotation C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to add the Authorization Header in a custom defined attribute on my Controller Methods.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("searchUser")]
    [Authorize]
    [Admin(Token = this.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"])]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDTO>> SearchUser(string SearchString)
    {
        var user = await userService.GetUsersFromSearchString(SearchString);
        return UserDTO.getDTOfromDbObject(user);
    }
```

Basically like this, but I get an error that I can´t use 'this'.
Is there any other way to pass the Request Header to my custom Attribute?

Comment: try like this:
HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

string authHeader = this.httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

Comment: Attribute declarations must use constants. Why not create your own type of Filter Attribute and extract and compare the header token there?

Comment: you can access it directly `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]` in your custom Attribute

Comment: the first method wont work, and i dont have to HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"] in my Attribute Object